# varchar2(n BYTE|CHAR) default -> CHAR or BYTE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am supporting code that has below schema declaration:-

```
create table sample (
        id number Primary key,
        username varchar2(100),
);
```

I looked up on Oracle documentation & varchar2 has two declaration modes
varchar2(n BYTE) and varchar2(n CHAR), If I don't specify explicitly BYTE or CHAR
& just declare username varchar2(500) then will 500 BYTES be allocated or 500 characters?

thanks,

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The default will be whatever your `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` parameter is set to.  By default, that is `BYTE` to be consistent with older versions of Oracle where there was no option to use character length semantics.  If you are defining your own schema and you are using a variable width character set (like AL32UTF8), I'd strongly recommend setting `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` to CHAR because you almost always intended to specify lengths in characters not in bytes.

Comment: You might want to add that setting NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS to CHAR will *not* overcome the limit of 4000 **bytes** for a VARCHAR column.

Comment: at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e24448/initparams149.htm)  page it says: _Caution:
Oracle strongly recommends that you do NOT set the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter to CHAR in the instance or server parameter file. This may cause many existing installation scripts to unexpectedly create columns with character length semantics, resulting in runtime errors, including buffer overflows._  As you said it's almost always intended to specify lengths in characters. That really discourages me. what should I do know, every now and then I need to increase some column size.

Comment: @mkb - The parameter can be set at the session level as well.  Set the parameter at the session level when you're defining your objects if you don't want the risk of having it set at the instance level.  Or just set it at the instance level back to BYTE before running an Oracle installation script.

Comment: Attention. I stumbled across this: when using Oracle SQL Developer, the parameter is also overwritten in your session if it is set here: Preferences - Database: NLS - Length

Answer (score 13):

You might check your current value using the following query:

```
SELECT
  value

FROM
  NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS

WHERE
  parameter='NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';
```

Comment: Its 'value' and not 'val'

Comment: SHOW PARAMETER NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS