# ALTER statement: Why VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) instead of VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)?

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, oracle11g

I executed the following (Oracle 11g) SQL statement to *increase* an existing column's length from VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) to VARCHAR2(50 CHAR):

```
ALTER TABLE USERX.MY_TABLE MODIFY (LASTNAME VARCHAR2(50));
```

It succeeded without incident, but when I look at the new `Data Type` column, I see: `VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)` instead of `VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)`.

My questions are:

1. Why **BYTE** and not CHAR? What have I done incorrectly?
2. How do I fix the column's length to be `VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)`?

Comment: You might find the answer here [varchar2(n BYTE|CHAR) default -> CHAR or BYTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477564/varchar2n-bytechar-default-char-or-byte)

Comment: @A.B.Cade Thank you! That provided enough information for me to come up with the answer. I didn't know about that default thingy. :)

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to upvote the answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7477609/1083652) post

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering myself (thanks to the tip provided [by this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7477609/146325)):

I should have executed instead:

```
ALTER TABLE USERX.MY_TABLE MODIFY (LASTNAME VARCHAR2(50 CHAR));
```

(note the extra `CHAR` after 50)