# Difference between varchar2(16 Char) and varchar2(16)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

In one table I am defining field as

```
FORACID VARCHAR2(16 CHAR)
```

Output of query : `select foracid from tbaadm.gam where rownum <= 5;`

```
FORACID
----------------------------------------------------------------
00000063011015
00000063011028
00000063011024
00000063011023
00000441021004
```

In another table I am defining field as

```
FORACID VARCHAR2(16)
```

Output of query : `select foracid from tbaadm.gam where rownum <= 5;`

```
FORACID
----------------
0382010021491
UB3
3667
PCAP
LO-CCA2
```

You can see that in the first query, the spool is of size 64 (i.e 16 char i.e 16*4=64)
In the second query, the spool is of 16 size (i.e 16 byte i.e 16*1 = 16)

How can I make the spool output of first query also to show only 16 size.?
Is it possible?

Comment: `VARCHAR2(16 CHAR)` will store 16 characters whereas `VARCHAR2(16)` is shorthand for `VARCHAR2(16 BYTE)` which will store 16 bytes (so for multi-byte characters this will store less than 16 characters).

Comment: @MT0: I don't believe that's quite correct. The meaning of `VARCHAR2(16)` depends on how NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS is set up. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477564/varchar2n-bytechar-default-char-or-byte) for a better explanation.

Comment: @BobJarvis The default is `BYTE` but, yes, I'll agree that it depends on that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can [format SQL/Plus reports (spooled queries)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm) by issuing [formatting directives](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm#BACHCABF) before the query

```
COLUMN FORACID FORMAT A16;                          -- A = Alphabetic, 16 = Column Width
SELECT FORACID FROM tbaadm.gam WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
```